# C# MessageBox casues key handler to ignore SurpressKeyPress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Consider Windows Forms application with following components

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        textBox.Multiline = true;

        Controls.Add(this.textBox);
        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            if (textBox.Text.Length > 10)
                MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, expected behaviour, is to write text to `textBox` and press enter. If the text is

- not long enough, nothing should happen (due to `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`) and that happens.
- is long enough, empty `MessageBox` should pop up and `Keys.Enter` should not reach the `textBox` component. However, when MessageBox pops up, the text will contain line-break caused by the enter.

Is this intended behaviour, or bug, or am I the only on experiencing this?

Comment: MessageBox is dangerous when used in the wrong spot, same kind of danger as the infamous DoEvents().  It causes *re-entrancy* problems.  It screws up your SuppressKeyPress request since that won't be done until after your event handler completes.  Which won't happen until after the message box closes.  Since MessageBox dispatches messages, it will dispatch the KeyPress as well so SuppressKeyPress has no effect whatsoever.  The fix is simple, use textBox.MaxLength = 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by calling the message box using `BeginInvoke` this way:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            if (textBox.Text.Length > 10)
                MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }));
    }
}
```