# Showing a MessageBox cancels SupressKeyPress=true

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a form with a multiline `TextBox` on it. When the user wants to create a new line, he should press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when he presses only <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing should happen. So here is my code:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
    {
        int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = pos + 2;
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        return;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.

When the user presses only <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I want to show a `MessageBox`, so I added the following line:

```
    ...
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello"); // <-- Here
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

The problem is that now after the `MessageBox` is shown, the cursor goes down one line, which I do not want.

How can I fix that? I tried to change the order between the `MessageBox` and the keypress suppression but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MessageBox casues key handler to ignore SurpressKeyPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533361/c-sharp-messagebox-casues-key-handler-to-ignore-surpresskeypress)

Comment: You need to replace `MessageBox.Show("Hello");` with 
`this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `e.KeyCode` instead of `e.KeyData` in the `Keys.Enter`-only condition. `e.KeyCode` will be set to `Keys.Enter` in any case, when <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is pressed or not.

Advancing the position by 2 is not needed: when you insert a new piece of text, the caret position is updated *automatically*.

Note that setting `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` also sets `e.Handled = true;`: [Net source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/KeyEvent.cs,182)

**Note**: Using a RichTextBox, you don't need to `BeginInvoke` the MessageBox to lose the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press. The TextBox control has the [AcceptReturn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn) property. The key is passed back when you close the MessageBox. No matter what is the value of the property.

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello")));
    }

    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
    {
        textBox1.SelectedText = "\r\n";
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make your code work. The new line is still added when pressing enter, after dismissing the message box.

Comment: Your code won't work, check the linked answer and @Hans's comment.

Comment: I forgot to paste the `BeginInvoke()` part. Sorry. I have tested it on a RichTextBox instead of a TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that you are creating another control (the **MessageBox**) from the handler for the original control. Probably that *resets* the *supresskeypress* flag.

EDIT: the reason is more subtle, I reproduce the comment of @Hans Passant from the linked answer linked by @Nouman:

> MessageBox is dangerous when used in the wrong spot, same kind of
>   danger as the infamous DoEvents(). It causes re-entrancy problems. It
>   screws up your SuppressKeyPress request since that won't be done until
>   after your event handler completes. Which won't happen until after the
>   message box closes. Since MessageBox dispatches messages, it will
>   dispatch the KeyPress as well so SuppressKeyPress has no effect
>   whatsoever.

I was able to reproduce the problem in my Linux box, using **Mono 5.20.1** and the Xamarin's implementation of *WinForms*.

What about a status bar instead of a **MessageBox**? If you can change that, then the following code will do the trick. If not, following the linked answer you will find a solution in the form of *BeginInvoke()*.

```
public class MainWindowCtrl
{
    public MainWindowCtrl()
    {
        this.view = new MainWindowView();

        this.view.Editor.KeyDown += (sender, e) => this.OnEditorKeyDown( e );
        this.view.FormClosed += (sender, e) => Application.Exit();

        this.view.Show();
    }

    void OnEditorKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.view.StatusBar.Text = "Ready";

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.view.StatusBar.Text = "Press Shift + Return!!";
            //MessageBox.Show( "Press Shift + Return!!" );
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
        {
            int pos = this.view.Editor.SelectionStart;

            this.view.Editor.SelectedText = System.Environment.NewLine;
            this.view.Editor.SelectionStart = pos + 2;

            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    MainWindowView view;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

"Messagebox.show" It prevents updates of ui and subsequent code from proceeding but does not prevent event processing.

```cs
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
    {
        int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = pos + 2;
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        return;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

In this code you changed "e.SuppressKeyPress" but events on the window have already processed your input.

```cs
private bool test = false;

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (test)
    {
        test = false;
        textBox1.Text += "Test";
    }
}

private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
    {
        int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = pos + 2;
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        return;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        test = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        test = false;
    }
}
```

It can be checked through the corresponding code.

If you type "Enter" "Test" is added to textbox

```cs
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
    {
        int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = pos + 2;
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        return;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }));

        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

You can use BeginInvoke

Comment: Confirmed: BeginInvoke() and Thread(...).Start() works when using MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

I found a little 'hack' for those who dont want to mess with Invoking methods, starting new threads manually etc.

My (old) code that didnt work was

```
private void textEditKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 220)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;                
                MessageBox.Show( @"\ not allowed. Use / instead.");

            }
        }
```

By changing the code to

```
private async void tEditDropBoxFolderName_EditValueChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 220)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                await Task.Delay(100);
                MessageBox.Show( @"\ not allowed. Use / instead.");

            }
        }
```

Everything works fine, and i havent found any side effects by using this.